# Exact meaning of the sentence.."Iterator itr=al.iterator(); "

Tags: java, collections, iterator

```
Iterator itr=al.iterator();
```

how does this line eactly work? does it just store the arraylist al in iterator? Can anyone pls give me a detailed explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It calls the `iterator()` method, which returns a reference to a suitable `Iterator` object. That's all we can tell from that code. If you're interested in the *implementation*, I suggest you look at the source.

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html#Iterator) to learn about iterators.

Comment: Means whenever you want to sequentially display an arraylist or any such class you need to initialize it like this?

Comment: you can iterate over the list any way you want, you don't have to get an instance of the iterator and call next()

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation :

An iterator over a collection. Iterator takes the place of Enumeration in the Java Collections Framework. Iterators differ from enumerations in two ways:
Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics.
Method names have been improved.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Basically the iterator maintains a position for iterating over a collection. It can be used to iterate over a collection, with the option of modifying the collection while iterating over it without a ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator%28%29):

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can access a collection through an iterator, you must obtain one. Each of the collection classes provides an iterator( ) method that returns an iterator to the start of the collection. By using this iterator object, you can access each element in the collection, one element at a time.